# How to integrate mustache template to read json data and dynamically display it in Chartjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, chart.js, mustache

I tried to pass data from data.json to mustache template in order to create bar graph.
I am unable to figure out where exactly I need to pass the data to get the graph right.
Please help me to figure out by reviewing the following code snippets.

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
    <canvas height="200px" width="300px" id="bar-graph"></canvas>
</div>

<script>
     const barCtx = document.getElementById('bar-graph').getContext('2d');
     new Chart(barCtx, barGraphConfig());
     function barGraphConfig() {    
    return {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        datasets: [{
          data: {{barGraph}},
          borderRadius: 5,
          backgroundColor: [
            '#fece8c',
            '#a28cfe',
            '#a28cfe',
            '#feab8c',
            '#8ca2fe',
            '#8ca2fe',
          ],
          barThickness: 20
        }],
        labels: ['AAA', 'AA', 'A', 'BBB', 'BB', 'B']
      },
      options: {
        plugins: { legend: { display: false } },
        showTooltip: false,
        animation: {
          duration: 0,
          onComplete: renderDataLabel,
        },
        parsing: {
          xAxisKey: 'sector',
          yAxisKey: 'value'
        },
        scales: {
          x: {
            grid: {
              borderWidth: 3,
              borderColor: '#232323',
              display: false,
            },
          },
          y: {
            display: false,
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }
      },
    };
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**data.json**

```
barGraph: [
  {
    "name": "A",
    "value": 4
  },
  {
    "name": "AAA",
    "value": 10
  },
  {
    "name": "B",
    "value": 40
  },
  {
    "name": "BB",
    "value": 20
  },
  {
    "name": "BBB",
    "value": 7
  }
]
```

The error we are getting

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the structure of the data.json as `dataset.data`. But to enable CHART.JS to read correctly the data, you should set `options.parsing` option at chart level, as following:

```
options: {   
  parsing: {
    xAxisKey: 'name',
    yAxisKey: 'value'
  }    
}
```

See documentation of CHART.JS: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/data-structures.html#object-using-custom-properties

```js
const barGraph = [
  {
    "name": "A",
    "value": 4
  },
  {
    "name": "AAA",
    "value": 10
  },
  {
    "name": "B",
    "value": 40
  },
  {
    "name": "BB",
    "value": 20
  },
  {
    "name": "BBB",
    "value": 7
  }
];     

const barCtx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
     new Chart(barCtx, barGraphConfig());
     function barGraphConfig() {
      return {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        datasets: [
        {
          data: barGraph,
          borderRadius: 5,
          backgroundColor: [
            '#fece8c',
            '#a28cfe',
            '#a28cfe',
            '#feab8c',
            '#8ca2fe',
            '#8ca2fe',
          ],
          barThickness: 20
        }
      ],
    },
    options: {   
      parsing: {
        xAxisKey: 'name',
        yAxisKey: 'value'
      }    
    }
  };
}
```

```css
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.9.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="myChartDiv">
      <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, We are using mustache.js to inject values inside the `.html` file. This HTML file contains HTML code and the script code. We need the data generated from our Js functions to be injected in the script tag code.

Comment: Update the code block in the question as well, as per your suggestion.